# xCode: setView always portrait though device in Landscape

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I have encountered a problem developing an iPad app with xCode.

When I load a view into my rootViewController like this

```
[self setView:viewController.view];
```

The view is always displayed in Portrait even though the device is rotated to landscape.

I checked all options and tried changing the shouldAutoRotateToOrientation method and it seems to have nothing to do with it. 
If I rotate the device to portrait and then back to landscape it works.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Best regards,

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was nesting viewControllers which leads to bad behavior like rotation notifications not being sent to certain ViewControllers.